# Haskell -- Functions Taking Function As An Argument

Tags: haskell

I have written a couple of functions and want to call them in the main function. And I keep having type errors in ghci.

Here's my main function:

```
renderMaze :: [((Integer,Integer), (Integer,Integer))] -> [String]
renderMaze = getHash known xs
    where
        known = getCoordinates
        xs = grid m n
            where
                m = maximumBy(comparing fst). getCoordinates
                n = maximumBy(comparing snd). getCoordinates

getHash :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)] -> [String]

path :: ((Integer, Integer), (Integer, Integer)) -> [(Integer, Integer)]

getCoordinates :: [((Integer,Integer) , (Integer,Integer))] -> [(Integer,Integer)]

grid :: Int -> Int -> [(Int,Int)]
```

I omitted the body of each function

Below are my errors:

```
? Couldn't match expected type: [((Integer, Integer),
                                      (Integer, Integer))]
                                    -> [String]
                  with actual type: [String]
    ? Possible cause: ‘getHash’ is applied to too many arguments


 ? Couldn't match expected type: [(Int, Int)]
                  with actual type: [((Integer, Integer), (Integer, Integer))]
                                    -> [(Integer, Integer)]
    ? Probable cause: ‘known’ is applied to too few arguments


? Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
                  with actual type ‘t1 (a2, b0) -> (a2, b0)’
    ? Probable cause: ‘m’ is applied to too few arguments


? Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’
                  with actual type ‘t0 (a0, a1) -> (a0, a1)’
    ? Probable cause: ‘n’ is applied to too few arguments
```

Comment: What is your question? What errors do you get?

Comment: In your code, `known, n, m` are all defined as _functions_. I guess you did not mean to do that. You likely expected that the input of `renderMaze` (which you did not name) gets automatically passed to such functions, but this is not the case. I'd start by writing `renderMaze maze = ...` and passing `maze` around as needed.

Comment: You're not passing any arguments anywhere.  You will need to do that.

Comment: Possibly not of immediate help, but consider defining some type aliases at least (`type Point = (Integer, Integer)`), if not some custom product types (`data Point = Pt Integer Integer`) to simplify your code and your type signatures.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, in part, with @chepner. A datatype for points could be good, but type aliases are often more confusing than helpful.

Comment: I pointed that out mostly just as the simplest way to make the type signature half as long :)